# Intercept Form POST request in WebView

Tags: android, post, android-webview

I'm trying to add authorization headers in every request in WebView. I can override shouldOverrideUrlLoading method for GET request, but I can't get POST request to work. I have tried many answer from this site, and none of them works. Is there a proper way to do this?

Edit:

For GET Request I use:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString(), getHeader());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url, getHeader());
            return true;
        }
}
```

I used WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest() to intercept POST request. But somehow the request I create became GET.

Comment: Please explain shortly what you have tried.

Comment: Is the website your own? I mean can you adapt the page?

Comment: Please show your code while adding headers during GET.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question @greenapps

Comment: Isnt `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` triggered with a POST ? Or `shouldInterceptRequest()` ? And what do you mean with 'a post became get' ?

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not triggered by a POST. I mean, I tried to intercept it using shouldInterceptRequest() by override with new WebResourceResponse. But the WebResourceResponse I create return a GET method @greenapps

Comment: Pretty unclear what you did for making post work. And with no code... And i do not understand what you mean with that a post becomes a get. You should take the time to show us exactly what you did and what happens.